# Sigma+ quark structure

Tags: quarks, baryons

Does sigma+ have 2 quark structures, if so are they uus and (anti)d (anti)d (anti)s ? Both these structures are the same charge (+) so I guess it would make sense however I  can't find much about it online anywhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_baryon     my knowledge is not great, so apologies if I am out of my depth, and I will delete this comment if it is inappropriate. I can see the quarks listed and wiki just says the same as you for the antiquarks

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm guessing there must be 2 structures but I'm not sure, wiki seems to agree even if not directly :)

Comment: ??? You wrote a baryon and an anti baryon, with opposite baryon numbers, but the same charge, and you expect them to be "two structures"?? the first decays to a neutron and pion and the second one to an antineutron and pion.

Comment: Yes since the charges are both positive  overall and the baryon is sigma+, unless there is an anti sigma-. In which case I was unaware and I apologise.

Comment: Of course the antiSigma(-), which is positive, is different than the Sigma+.  They have ***opposite strangeness*** and baryon number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anti quark structure is not the structure for sigma+ but anti sigma- as mentioned by @CosmasZachos in the comments

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I appreciate this is a cut and paste answer, (which I detest) because I would rather rewrite it to learn something from, but it's 1.00 am here so.... but if you click on the link below it might help. The website below has not been maintained, so you might take a while to resolve it on your machine,  sorry.

Extracts From: [Sigma Bayon](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/sigma.html)

> The sigma is a baryon which contains a strange quark. The quark composition of the three different sigmas is shown above. The three varieties have similar masses and are said to be an isospintriplet. The only baryon with a strange quark which is less massive than the sigma is the neutral lambda baryon. The neutral sigma can decay to the lambda without violatingconservation of strangeness, so it proceeds rapidly by the electromagnetic interaction. The sigma-zero and lambda-zero have the same quark constituents so the sigma-zero can be considered to be an electromagnetic excited state of the lambda-zero. The charged sigmas have no decay path which does not involve the transmutation of the strange quark, so their decays are much slower, proceeding only by the weak interaction.
>
> According to the Particle Data Book, the branching ratio for the decays of the sigma-plus is 51.57% for the pπ0 pathway and 48.31% for the nπ+ pathway. This near equivalence is really surprising to me - the neutron pathway looks a lot harder.